# How to access block parameters using Object.send

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
class RentLimit < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.load_data
    rows = CSV.open("csvs/income_limits_2011_to_2015.csv").read
    rows.shift
    rows.each do |county, yr, date, _50pct_1br, _50pct_2br, _50pct_3br, _50pct_4br, _60pct_1br, _60pct_2br, _60pct_3br, _60pct_4br|
      [50, 60].each do |ami|
        [1, 2, 3, 4].each do |br|
          r = new
          r.county = county
          r.state = "SC"
          r.year = yr
          r.effective_date = Date.parse(date)
          r.pct_ami = ami
          r.br = br
          r.max_rent = self.send("_#{ami}pct_#{br}br".to_sym)
          r.save
        end#of brs
      end# of amis
    end# of rows
  end
end
```

but am getting this error message when trying to run it:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `_50pct_1br' for #<Class:0x007fe942ce3b18>
```

The `send` method isn't able to access those block parameters inside of the scope. Is there any way to give access to block parameters to `send`? If not, how else might I dynamically access block parameters?

How do I use `send` or its equivalent to access block parameters in Ruby?

Comment: I kind of agree with whoever downvoted this question. The whole approach to the coding is crap. I ended up just using eval(). also voting to close

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you tell `CSV.open` what your column names are. It looks like your CSV file might have a header row that you're skipping with `rows.shift`, in which case you shouldn't skip it, and use the `headers: true` option. Then you can access each field by name with `row["field_name"]` or, in your case, `row["_#{ami}pct_#{br}br"]`:

```
CSV_PATH = "csvs/income_limits_2011_to_2015.csv"

DEFAULT_STATE = "SC"

def self.load_data
  CSV.open(CSV_PATH, 'r', headers: true) do |csv|
    csv.each do |row|
      max_rent = row["_#{ami}pct_#{br}br"]

      create(
        county: row["county"],
        state: DEFAULT_STATE,
        year: row["yr"],
        effective_date: Date.parse(row["date"]),
        pct_ami: ami,
        br: br,
        max_rent: max_rent,
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I used `CSV.open` with a block to ensure that the file is closed after it's been read, which your original code wasn't doing. I also used `create` instead of `new; ... save`, since the latter is needlessly verbose.

If you're skipping the first row for some other reason, or you want to use field names other than those in the header row, you can set the options `return_headers: false, headers: names`, where `names` is an array of names, e.g.:

```
CSV_HEADERS = %w[
  county yr date _50pct_1br _50pct_2br _50pct_3br _50pct_4br
  _60pct_1br _60pct_2br _60pct_3br _60pct_4br
].freeze

def self.load_data
  CSV.open(CSV_PATH, 'r', return_headers: false, headers: CSV_HEADERS) do |csv|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Finally, since some of your attributes are the same for every object created, I'd move those out of the loop:

```
def self.load_data
  base_attrs = { state: DEFAULT_STATE, pct_ami: ami, br: br }

  CSV.open(CSV_PATH, 'r', headers: true) do |csv|
    csv.each do |row|
      create(base_attrs.merge(
        county: row["county"],
        year: row["yr"],
        effective_date: row["date"],
        max_rent: row["_#{ami}pct_#{br}br"]
      ))
    end
  end
end
```